# Fadeout animation happens much later than intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, onscroll

I want to change the opacity of an element while scrolling, then change it back once scrolling has stopped. This is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".BGlogoCircle").fadeTo( "fast", 1);
    console.log("scrolled");
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $(".BGlogoCircle").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
        console.log("stopped");
    }, 250));
});
```

It only half-works, as the first part works fine: I scroll, the element fades in, and `console.log('scrolled')` fires.

As soon as I stop scrolling, `console.log("stopped")` fires, but then the element only fades out much later (around 5 seconds or so, I reckon).

Where is my mistake and how can I fix this?

Comment: Create a fiddle by adding your remaining codes.

Answer (score 1):

You queue a lot of `fadeTo` animations with this:

```
$(".BGlogoCircle").fadeTo( "fast", 1);
```

As jQuery keeps all launched animations (on the same element) in a queue and treats them only when the previously queued animation is finished, it will only get to the `0.5` animation when all previous animations are done. There could be a lot of those, since the `scroll` event fires repeatedly during a typical scroll action.

You should better [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) any previous one, before launching the next, so that the animation queue remains empty:

```
$(".BGlogoCircle").stop().fadeTo( "fast", 1);
```

This solves the issue, but I would suggest to do the same with the other call to `fadeTo`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".BGlogoCircle").stop().fadeTo( "fast", 1);
    console.log("scrolled");
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $(".BGlogoCircle").stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
        console.log("stopped");
    }, 250));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".BGlogoCircle").fadeIn("slow");
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    // do something
    $(".BGlogoCircle").fadeOut("slow");
  }, 250));
});
```

```css
.cool {
  height: 1000px;
}
.BGlogoCircle {
  background: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="cool">
    <div class="BGlogoCircle">Test</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```